# Where clause missing in SQL Query

Tags: mysql

I am sending  a SQL query from a client to a MySQL database.
When I run the query in MySQL the result is correct.

The result from the query is wrong, when sent from client.
The last WHERE clause is missing.

The query original looks like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Second_In_State) From 
(SELECT 
    Time_Stamp, 
    State,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, LAG(Time_Stamp) OVER(ORDER BY Time_Stamp), Time_Stamp)
AS Second_In_State
FROM db.xyz_1_state
ORDER BY Time_Stamp) AS T
Where State = 1;
```

Result is number of seconds where State = 1 (The wanted result)

In the MySQL Query log the query looks like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Second_In_State) From 
(SELECT 
    Time_Stamp, 
    State,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, LAG(Time_Stamp) OVER(ORDER BY Time_Stamp), Time_Stamp)
AS Second_In_State
FROM db.xyz_1_state
ORDER BY Time_Stamp) AS T
```

The result is the total of seconds in all states. (Wrong result)

Any suggestions why the last line is missing?

Comment: Assuming your log output can be believed, the only way you could see the version of the query with the `WHERE` clause missing is if your code is executing this same query.

Comment: What's your question ? could you provide some samlpe data and expect result?

Comment: I have tried to explain the problem a little better. 
My question is why the last line is missing, when query is sent from client?

Comment: Try making your last `Where` in uppercase (`WHERE`), on the small chance this is the issue. I don't expect it to be, but depending on your setup and environment there is a small chance this is the cause.

Comment: 'I am sending a SQL query from a client' - what client (mysql command line?) ? 'to mysql' - where (same server , remote server)

Comment: I have looked a bit more into the problem. And found the client log. The client is not sending the last line of the query in the connection string. 
The client is Machine SCADA Expert. I must contact their support.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments.

I found out that the client is limited in number of lines. So when saving the last line is deleted.

So converting the query to a single line, solved the problem.

Thanks.